# Karabiner-Elements でCommand+ArrowキーをOption+Arrowキーに変換したい

Tags: macos

初めて質問します。

プログラミング、というのとはちょっと違うのですが
プログラマの人はよくつかっているということで、
Karabiner-Elements の設定について質問します。

MacBook Pro で、macOS Sierra使いはじめました。

キー配置カスタマイズソフトの
Karabiner と Seli が OS のバージョンアップにともなって
動かなくなったので、
Karabiner-Elements を導入したのですが

Karabiner-Elements で、単純なキーの置き換え方法、
Jsonファイルの編集方法はわかったのですが
複数キーの組み合わせを、変更する方法がわからないです。

具体的には、タイトルに書いたように
Command+ArrowLeft や +ArrowRight を
Option+ArrowLeft や +ArrowRight に変換したいのです。

どなたかご存知のかた、教えてください。

Jsonファイルの設定方法は、下記を参考にしています。
このページでは、2つのキーの設定がのっていないのと、
そもそも、Karabiner-Elements では対応していないのかもしれません。
(Karabinerでは対応してたんですけどね...)

http://qiita.com/naoya_t/items/45f0557cb29f2c2e8e3c

どなたかご存知でしたら、教えてください。

よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下のような感じでいかがでしょうか。試してないので間違っているかもしれません。

```
        "complex_modifications": {
            "parameters": {
                "basic.to_if_alone_timeout_milliseconds": 1000
            },
            "rules": [
                {
                    "manipulators": [
                        {
                            "description": "Map cmd-left to opt+left",
                            "from": {
                                "key_code": "left_arrow",
                                "modifiers": {
                                    "mandatory": [ "left_command" ]
                                }
                            },
                            "to": [
                                {
                                    "key_code": "left_arrow",
                                    "modifiers": [
                                        "left_option"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "type": "basic"
                        },
                        {
                            "description": "Map cmd-right to opt+right",
                            "from": {
                                "key_code": "right_arrow",
                                "modifiers": {
                                    "mandatory": [ "left_command" ]
                                }
                            },
                            "to": [
                                {
                                    "key_code": "right_arrow",
                                    "modifiers": [
                                        "left_option"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "type": "basic"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
```

↓ここにサンプルがいくつかありますので、参考になさると良いかと思います。
https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/tree/master/examples

> (Karabinerでは対応してたんですけどね...)

Karabiner もそのうち対応してくれると思いますよ。

Comment: ちょっと環境を変えてしまい、確認ができないのですが、
お返事、感謝いたします。
ありがとうございます。